# Wikipedia's definition of isolated point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Wikipedia defines an [isolated point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) of a subset $S \subseteq X$ to be a point $x \in S$ such that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ not containing any other points of $S$.  Furthermore, it claims that this is equivalent to saying $\{x\}$ is open in $X$.

Question: How is the last sentence true?  This seems to be false since for example $1$  is an isolated point of $\{1\} \cup (3, 4)$, but $\{1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not open.

Comment: No, the last sentence is false. It means that $\{x\}$ is open in $S$.

Comment: I've corrected Wikipedia.

Comment: It's a silly definition - there really isn't a reason to talk about subsets. A point $x$ in a space is isolated if $\{x\}$ is open in that space. We often talk about isolated elements in subspaces, but the definition works without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should (and now does) say that $x$ is isolated in $S$ iff $\{x\}$ is open in $S$, not in $X$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too.

Answer (score 3):

This is true only if $S$ is open. Notice that in your example, $S=\{1\} \cup (3, 4)$ is not an open set in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.